# Way to consume bulk messages from Service Bus Queue instead of triggering it for each message

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-functions

We have a Service Bus Queue; we are thinking to handle messages through Service Bus Queue Trigger in the Azure Function. But we want to consume bulk messages (in a loop) instead of re-triggering Function App for each message. What should be the way to achieve this and by using which handler. Should Azure Function be only used or we can host an App Service for consuming the same.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use batches. Simply declare the variable as an array.

```
public static class ProcessOrders
{
    [FunctionName("ProcessOrders")]
    public static void Run(
        [ServiceBusTrigger("orders", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")]
        Message[] orders, // <-- array
        ILogger log)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Number of orders: {orders.Length}");
    }
}
```

You can further configure [batch size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5%2Cextensionv3&pivots=programming-language-csharp#hostjson-settings) and such using the `host.json` file.